# templated functor called with templated types

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have these two functors:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity {
    const T &operator()(const T &x) const {
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename KeyFunction>
class key_helper {

public:
    key_helper(const KeyFunction& get_key_) : get_key(get_key_) { }

    template<typename T, typename K>
    const K operator()(const T& x, const int& n) {
        return get_key(x);
    }

private:
    KeyFunction get_key;
};
```

However, if i use the second functor in a templated function. I got errors:

```
template<typename T, typename K>
void test(T item, K key) {

    identity<T> id;
    key_helper<identity<T> > k(id);

    K key2 = k(item, 2); // compiler cannot deduce type of K
    key2 = k.operator()<T, K>(item, 2); // expected primary-expression before ',' token
}
```

How can i call the functor's `operator()` from the `test` function?

Comment: FYI If you have c++11 features available, you should be able to do something like `template<typename T> auto operator()(const T& x, const int& n) -> decltype(get_key(x)) { return get_key(x); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't deduce the return type of `operator()`, `K`, in any way, so you need to explicitly specify the template arguments. The reason your second attempt doesn't work is because you need to include the `template` keyword:

```
K key2 = k.template operator()<T,K>(item, 2);
```